# Can't user Custom Work Item Form in TFS 2018 Web portal

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm creating new User Story (WIT), I have installes tool: Process Editor under VS2018, connected to the project and exported WIT ( User Story ) then i have made some changes. While using previe window under VS2019 i see that changes has been made:
[image]

But while using Web portal i can't see my changes, there is only default Agile User Story view:
[image]

I have found information what could be the problem ( Enable the new form found on M$): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/manage-new-form-rollout?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops

I've checked all permissions and groups I'm in, inclding Administrator groups, for projects, whole collection ext.  On the M$ web site is information that i should click "Enable the new work item form" to be able to use customization i did. But i don't have this option :( :[image]

Can you please tell me what Am I doing wrong ? What have I missed ?

TFS2018 installed on premise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The using of the new work item form is already updated in your server. On VS you see the old style but on web you have the new style. On the [Process editor download page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte) you can find the following:

> Process Template: Open and edit a process template (you can only edit
>   the old-style work item forms, those that don’t reflect the new web
>   layout)

To update the new form check this page: [New web form layout-WebLayout and Control elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

Comment: I have already tried to modify WebLayout and still no progress. And still i can't Enable this new WIT in TFS, maybe this is a case

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this ticket:  [TFS work items opened inside Visual Study no longer open in the web browser, they always open in the Visual Studio editor](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/539058/tfs-work-items-opened-inside-visual-study-no-longe.html)

> *According to the response from MSFT:*
>
> We have re-design the default landing page for work items in Visual
>   Studio 2019 which only works with server >= 2019. **If server is <
>   2019, work items will be open in Visual Studio only**.

Since you are using TFS 2018 with VS2019, you may have to open work item in web portal from browser directly right now.

But work item in Visual Studio IDE is still using the **old Layout forms**. Work item in Web Portal is using the new layout. That's why you have seen different behavior.

Comment: But there is no TFS 2019 and no VS 2018 do how can i be compatible ?

Comment: @d3nver We changed TFS name from TFS2019 to **Azure DevOps Server 2019**, it is actually TFS 2019. Sorry for any inconvenience.